# getline ignores '\n' - getline with two delimiters

Tags: c++, csv, getline

In c++ I get a csv file of a matrix of the the form `float,float,float,\n` or `float float float \n` for each line respectively.

If I read the file line wise using `getline` the end line delimiter `\n` is always read as well, i.e. `getline(csv_file, csv_line, '\n')` or `getline(csv_file, csv_line)` gives as output `1,2,3,\n` and not `1,2,3,` as I expect it to. How can I specifically discard this `\n`?

Furthermore, how can I differentiate between those two input versions and store the particular delimiter `' '` or `','`?

Comment: Is it possible that the end-of-line marker is actually `\r\n` instead of just `\n`, so the `\r` is not getting discarded, but your platform is still treating it as a line break?

Comment: No it is just an '\n' at the end of each line

Comment: And how do you differentiate between the comma and space delimiters? Without knowing in advance what the delimiter will be obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, It's generally not a good idea to let data to be presented at different format per line.

But if it is, you can read all the line to string, using [this getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) with no delimeter and then parse string using regexp or simple string functions. You can define which format it is by trying to find `,` symbol at string. If you [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) it, then you need to split by comma, otherwise by whitespace.

Also have a look into `stringstream` class ([link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)). It's just for such cases when you need to slice some values from already readed strings (and not just having one type).